# Can this bound for the abundancy index of $n$ be improved, given that $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with $k=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

In what follows, set $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ to be the *abundancy index* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x$.  If $I(y)=2$ and $y$ is odd, then $y$ is called an odd perfect number.  Euler proved that an odd perfect number, if one exists, must have the so-called Eulerian form $N = q^k n^2$ where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

The following result was communicated to me (via e-mail, by Pascal Ochem) on April 17, 2013.

> If $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, then
>   $$I(n) > {\left(\frac{8}{5}\right)}^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} \approx 1.44440557.$$

The proof of this result uses the following lemma.

> Let $x(n) = \ln(I(n^2))/\ln(I(n))$.  If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, then
>   $$\min(x(a), x(b)) < x(ab) < \max(x(a),x(b)).$$

**Proof of Lemma:**  First, note that $x(a) \neq x(b)$ (since $\gcd(a , b) = 1$). Without loss of generality, we may assume that $x(a) < x(b)$.  Thus, since
$$x(n) = \frac{\ln(I(n^2))}{\ln(I(n))},$$
we have
$$\frac{\ln(I(a^2))}{\ln(I(a))} < \frac{\ln(I(b^2))}{\ln(I(b))}.$$
This implies that
$$\ln(I(a^2))\ln(I(b)) < \ln(I(b^2))\ln(I(a)).$$
Adding $\ln(I(a^2))\ln(I(a))$ to both sides of the last inequality, we get
$$\ln(I(a^2))\bigg(\ln(I(b)) + \ln(I(a))\bigg) < \ln(I(a))\bigg(\ln(I(b^2)) + \ln(I(a^2))\bigg).$$
Using the identity $\ln(X) + \ln(Y) = \ln(XY)$, we can rewrite the last inequality as
$$\ln(I(a^2))\ln(I(ab)) < \ln(I(a))\ln(I((ab)^2))$$
since $I(x)$ is a weakly multiplicative function of $x$ and $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.
It follows that
$$\min(x(a), x(b))  = x(a) = \frac{\ln(I(a^2))}{\ln(I(a))} < \frac{\ln(I((ab)^2))}{\ln(I(ab))} = x(ab).$$

Under the same assumption $x(a) < x(b)$, we can show that $$x(ab) < x(b) = \max(x(a),x(b))$$
by adding $\ln(I(b^2))\ln(I(b))$ ( instead of $\ln(I(a^2))\ln(I(a))$ ) to both sides of the inequality
$$\ln(I(a^2))\ln(I(b)) < \ln(I(b^2))\ln(I(a)).$$

This finishes the proof.

> > From this lemma, we note that $1 < x(n) < 2$ follows from
> >     $$I(n) < I(n^2) < {\left(I(n)\right)}^2$$
> >     and $I(n^2) = {\left(I(n)\right)}^{x(n)}$.
> >
> > The trivial lower bound for $I(n)$ is
> >     $${\bigg(\frac{8}{5}\bigg)}^{1/2} < I(n).$$
> >
> > Note that decreasing the denominator in the exponent gives an increase in the lower bound for $I(n)$.

**Proof of Result:** We sketch a proof for the mentioned result here, as communicated to the author by Pascal Ochem.

Suppose that $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form.

We want to obtain a lower bound on $I(n)$.  We know that
$$I(n^2) = 2/I(q^k) > 2/(5/4) = 8/5.$$
We need to improve the trivial bound $I(n^2) < {\left(I(n)\right)}^2$.

Let $x(n)$ be such that 
$$I(n^2) = {\bigg(I(n)\bigg)}^{x(n)}.$$

That is, $x(n) = \ln(I(n^2))/\ln(I(n))$.  We want an upper bound on $x(n)$ for $n$ odd.  By the lemma, we consider the component $r^s$ with $r$ prime that maximizes $x(r^s)$.

We have
$$I(r^s) = \frac{r^{s + 1} - 1}{{r^s}(r - 1)} = 1 + \frac{1}{r - 1} - \frac{1}{{r^s}(r - 1)}.$$
Also,
$$I(r^{2s}) = \frac{r^{2s + 1} - 1}{{r^{2s}}(r - 1)} = I(r^s)\bigg(1 + \left(\frac{1 - r^{-s}}{r^{s + 1} - 1}\right)\bigg).$$
So,
$$x(r^s) = \frac{\ln(I(r^{2s}))}{\ln(I(r^s))} = \frac{\ln(I(r^s)) + \ln(1 + \left(\frac{1 - r^{-s}}{r^{s + 1} - 1}\right))}{\ln(I(r^s))},$$
from which it follows that
$$x(r^s) = 1 + \frac{\ln(1 + \left(\frac{1 - r^{-s}}{r^{s + 1} - 1}\right))}{\ln(1 + \frac{1}{r - 1} - \frac{1}{{r^s}(r - 1)})}.$$
We can check that
$$x(r^s) > x(r^t)$$
if $s < t$ and $r \geq 3$.  Therefore, $x(r^s)$ is maximized for $s = 1$.
Now,
$$x(r) = 1 + \frac{\ln(1 + (1/(r(r + 1))))}{\ln(1 + (1/r))} = \frac{\ln(1 + (1/r) + (1/r)^2)}{\ln(1 + (1/r))} = \ln(I(r^2))/\ln(I(r)),$$ 
which is maximized for $r = 3$.
So,
$$x(3) = \ln(I(3^2))/\ln(I(3)) = \ln(13/9)/\ln(4/3) \approx 1.27823.$$

The claimed result then follows, and the proof is complete.

**Motivation for My Inquiry**

Note that, since $q$ is prime with $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $q \geq 5$.  In particular, when $k=1$, then we obtain
$$I(q^k) = 1 + \frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{6}{5} \iff I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} \geq \frac{5}{3},$$
from which we get
$$I(n) > \bigg(I(n^2)\bigg)^{1/{x(3)}} \geq \bigg(\frac{5}{3}\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} \approx 1.4912789897463723558.$$

Here is my question:

> Would it be possible to tweak the argument in this post in order to come up with a proof for the implication
>   $$k=1 \implies I(n) > \frac{3}{2}?$$

Answer (score 2):

(Not a complete answer.)

Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special/Euler prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

First off, we show the following lemma.

**Lemma 1** $I(n) \neq 3/2 = I(2)$

*Proof*  The proof is trivial and follows from the fact that $n \neq 2$, since $n$ must be odd.  (In fact, we know by Nielsen's latest result that $\omega(n) \geq 9$, where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.  In particular, this means that $n$ is composite.)  Note that $2$ is [solitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_number#Solitary_numbers) as it is prime.

Next, we prove the following implication.

**Theorem** $\bigg((k=1) \land (I(n) < 3/2)\bigg) \implies q=5$

*Proof* Since $k=1$, then we obtain
$$\frac{2q}{q+1}=I(n^2) \leq (I(n))^{\frac{\ln(13/9)}{\ln(4/3)}} < \bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(13/9)}{\ln(4/3)}}.$$
Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2q%2F(q%2B1)%20%3C%20(3%2F2)%5E(ln(13%2F9)%2Fln(4%2F3))), we get that $-1 < q < 5.23316$, from which we conclude that $q=5$, since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

In general, we can remove the assumption that $k=1$:

**Theorem** $I(n) < 3/2 \implies q=5$

*Proof* We proceed as follows:
$$\frac{2(q-1)}{q} < I(n^2) \leq (I(n))^{\frac{\ln(13/9)}{\ln(4/3)}} < \bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(13/9)}{\ln(4/3)}}.$$

Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2(q-1)%2Fq%20%3C%20(3%2F2)%5E(ln(13%2F9)%2Fln(4%2F3))), we obtain $0 < q < 6.23316$, which implies that $q=5$, since $q$ is a prime number satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

**Remarks:** Note that $I(n) > 3/2$ would also follow from the inequality $D(n) < s(n)$, where $D(n)=2n-\sigma(n)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $n$ and $s(n)=\sigma(n) - n$ is the [sum of the aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $n$.

Comment: Note that, if $q > 5$, then since $q$ is prime and $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we have that $q \geq 13$, so that we obtain
$$\frac{24}{13} \leq \frac{2(q-1)}{q} < I(n^2) < (I(n))^{\frac{\ln(13/9)}{\ln(4/3)}}$$
from which we get
$$I(n) > \bigg(\frac{24}{13}\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} \approx 1.6155087635466.$$

Comment: Notice that we also have the biconditional
$$\bigg(D(n) < \frac{n}{2} < s(n)\bigg) \iff I(n) > \frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then since we have the lower bound $$I(n) > \bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}},$$ hence we obtain the upper bound
$$\dfrac{D(n)}{s(n)}=\dfrac{2-I(n)}{I(n) - 1}<\dfrac{2 - \bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}}{\bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} - 1} \approx 1.2501968.$$

Comment: If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ and $k = 1$, then since we have the lower bound $$I(m) > \bigg(\dfrac{5}{3}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}},$$ hence we obtain the upper bound
$$\dfrac{D(m)}{s(m)}=\dfrac{2-I(m)}{I(m) - 1}<\dfrac{2 - \bigg(\dfrac{5}{3}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}}{\bigg(\dfrac{5}{3}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} - 1} \approx 1.03550329.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be a **hypothetical odd perfect number** given in *Eulerian form*.

This answer attempts to prove that the inequality $I(n) > 3/2$ holds unconditionally, using a variation on the factor chain method.

---

Assume to the contrary that $I(n) \leq 3/2$.  As shown in the other [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2977546/28816), $I(n) \neq 3/2$, and that $I(n) < 3/2$ implies $q = 5$.

We get the series of implications:
$$I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \implies q = 5 \implies 3 = \frac{q + 1}{2} \mid \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \mid n^2 \implies 3 \mid n \text{ (since } 3 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies \frac{4}{3} = I(3) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$3 \mid n^2 \implies 3^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(3^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2$$
$$\implies 13 \mid n^2 \implies 13 \mid n \text{ (since } 13 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies \frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{14}{13} = I(3)I(13) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$13 \mid n^2 \implies 13^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(13^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2 \implies 183 = 3\cdot{61} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 61 \mid n^2 \implies 61 \mid n \text{ (since } 61 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies \frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{14}{13}\cdot\frac{62}{61} = I(3)I(13)I(61) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$61 \mid n^2 \implies 61^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(61^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2 \implies 3783 = 3\cdot{13}\cdot{97} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 97 \mid n^2 \implies 97 \mid n \text{ (since } 97 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies \frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{14}{13}\cdot\frac{62}{61}\cdot\frac{98}{97} = I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$97 \mid n^2 \implies 97^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(97^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2 \implies 9507 = 3\cdot{3169} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 3169 \mid n^2 \implies 3169 \mid n \text{ (since } 3169 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$3169 \mid n^2 \implies 3169^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(3169^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2$$
$$\implies 10045731 = 3\cdot{3348577} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 3348577 \mid n^2 \implies 3348577 \mid n \text{ (since } 3348577 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$3348577 \mid n^2 \implies 3348577^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(3348577^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2$$
$$\implies 11212971273507 = 3\cdot{3737657091169} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 3737657091169 \mid n^2 \implies 3737657091169 \mid n \text{ (since } 3737657091169 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577)I(3737657091169) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$3737657091169 \mid n^2 \implies 3737657091169^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(3737657091169^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2$$
$$\implies 13970080531169648034877731 = 3\cdot{181}\cdot{26042690887}\cdot{987900542491} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 181 \mid n^2 \implies 181 \mid n \text{ (since } 181 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies 26042690887 \mid n^2 \implies 26042690887 \mid n \text{ (since } 26042690887 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies 987900542491 \mid n^2 \implies 987900542491 \mid n \text{ (since } 987900542491 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577)I(3737657091169)I(181)I(26042690887)I(987900542491) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$181 \mid n^2 \implies 181^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(181^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2 \implies 32943 = 3\cdot{79}\cdot{139} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 79 \mid n^2 \implies 79 \mid n \text{ (since } 79 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies 139 \mid n^2 \implies 139 \mid n \text{ (since } 139 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
But this implies that
$$I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577)I(3737657091169)I(181)I(26042690887)I(987900542491)I(79)I(139) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2},$$
where we have the approximation
$$I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577)I(3737657091169)I(181)I(26042690887)I(987900542491)I(79)I(139) \approx 1.512675290866383731626612,$$
which is a **contradiction**.

---

We therefore conclude that the inequality
$$I(n) > \frac{3}{2}$$
must hold unconditionally.

Comment: [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967) shows in this [comment to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297332/a-proposed-unconditional-factor-chain-proof-for-the-inequality-in-frac3?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment8949994_4297332) that this argument is flawed.