# Can this inequality involving the deficiency and sum of aliquot divisors be improved?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

In what follows, we let $n > 1$ be a positive integer.  The classical sum of divisors of $n$ is given by $\sigma_1(n)$.  Denote the abundancy index of $n$ by $I(n)=\sigma_1(n)/n$.

Denote the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $n$ by $D(n)=2n-\sigma_1(n)$, and denote the [sum of aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $n$ by $s(n)=\sigma_1(n)-n$.

**CLAIM**
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(n^2)} < \frac{D(n)}{s(n)}$$

**PROOF**
$$I(n) < I(n^2) \implies 2 - I(n^2) < 2 - I(n) \implies D(n^2) < nD(n) \implies \frac{D(n^2)}{n^2}<\frac{D(n)}{n}$$

$$I(n) < I(n^2) \implies I(n) - 1 < I(n^2) - 1 \implies ns(n) < s(n^2) \implies \frac{s(n)}{n} < \frac{s(n^2)}{n^2}$$

From the last two inequalities, we get
$$\bigg(\frac{D(n^2)}{n^2}<\frac{D(n)}{n}\bigg) \land \bigg(\frac{n^2}{s(n^2)}<\frac{n}{s(n)}\bigg).$$

Multiplying LHS and RHS of the two inequalities, we finally obtain
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(n^2)} < \frac{D(n)}{s(n)}.$$

Here are my questions:

> Can the inequality in the **CLAIM** be improved?  If so, how?

Comment: To the serial downvoter:  I doubt if your high reputation could compensate for your lack of empathy.

Comment: Ah. You are experiencing this also? It's very strange isn't it? I mean why no comment to explain why they disapprove so that we are given the opportunity to improve the content

Comment: @AdamL, indeed!

Comment: If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then since we have the lower bound $$I(m) > \bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}},$$ hence we obtain the upper bound
$$\dfrac{D(m)}{s(m)}=\dfrac{2-I(m)}{I(m) - 1}<\dfrac{2 - \bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}}{\bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} - 1} \approx 1.2501968.$$

Comment: If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ and $k = 1$, then since we have the lower bound $$I(m) > \bigg(\dfrac{5}{3}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}},$$ hence we obtain the upper bound
$$\dfrac{D(m)}{s(m)}=\dfrac{2-I(m)}{I(m) - 1}<\dfrac{2 - \bigg(\dfrac{5}{3}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}}{\bigg(\dfrac{5}{3}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} - 1} \approx 1.03550329.$$

Comment: This question is closely related to this [earlier inquiry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967348).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am yet to find a counterexample for the following, I have not spent much time on your problem so will appreciate if this is not considered an improvement on your original inequality, but none the less I hope that it helps in some small way:

Denoting the Kronecker delta as follows:
$$\delta \left( x,y \right) =\cases{1&$x=y$\cr 0&$x\neq y $\cr}\tag{                             0}$$

up to $n \leq 2 \cdot 10^7$ I have found the following to be satisfied:
$${\frac {D \left( n \right) }{s \left( n \right) }}-{\frac {
D \left( {n}^{2} \right) }{s \left( {n}^{2} \right) }}-\frac{1}{4}
\delta \left( n-2\,\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor,1 \right) \lt \frac{3}{4} \tag{1}$$

Comment: What CAS did you use to test your conjecture, @AdamL?

Comment: Maple 16. I have it currently running up to $10^6$ but it is taking a lot of time, so it is likely I am reaching a physical limit regarding processing power

Comment: Maple is a licensed (i.e. paid) software, right?

Comment: I'll create a chat room for us.

Comment: The room name is your name btw.

Comment: An upvote for now, @AdamL.  Thank you for your time and attention.  =)

Comment: not a problem mate it is a very interesting subject I will add any further work I do on it in the future

Comment: Gladly accepting your answer now, @AdamL.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer in the context of *odd perfect numbers* $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Based from a formula in this [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3746548), we have
$$D(x)D(y)-D(xy)=2s(x)s(y)$$
when $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

In particular, since $p^k m^2$ is perfect (and $\gcd(p,m)=\gcd(p^k,m^2)=1$), we obtain $D(p^k m^2) = 0$, so that
$$D(p^k)D(m^2)=2s(p^k)s(m^2).$$
This last equation is equivalent to
$$\frac{D(m^2)}{s(m^2)}=\frac{2s(p^k)}{D(p^k)}.$$
But using the same formula, since $\gcd(p,m)=\gcd(p^k,m)=1$ we obtain
$$D(p^k)D(m)-D(p^k m)=2s(p^k)s(m).$$
Dividing throughout the last equation by $D(p^k)s(m)$, we get
$$\frac{D(m)}{s(m)}-\frac{D(p^k m)}{D(p^k)s(m)}=\frac{2s(p^k)}{D(p^k)}.$$
Equating the two expressions for
$$\frac{2s(p^k)}{D(p^k)}$$
we derive
$$\frac{D(m^2)}{s(m^2)}=\frac{D(m)}{s(m)}-\frac{D(p^k m)}{D(p^k)s(m)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

This answer adds further details to this [earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3747350/28816).

As before, let $p^k m^2$ be an *odd perfect number* with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Note that we have the numerical bounds
$$1 < I(p^k) < \frac{5}{4} < \bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} < I(m) < 2.$$

We have obtained the equation
$$\frac{D(m)}{s(m)}-\frac{D(m^2)}{s(m^2)}=\frac{D(p^k m)}{D(p^k)s(m)}$$
from which we get
$$0 < \frac{D(p^k m)}{D(p^k)s(m)}=\frac{2 - I(p^k)I(m)}{(2 - I(p^k))(I(m) - 1)} < \dfrac{2-\bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}}{\dfrac{3}{4}\bigg(\bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} - 1\bigg)} \approx 1.666929067.$$

Comment: Conjecturally, $k=1$ always holds for an odd perfect number $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$.

This means that
$$1 < I(p^k) \leq \frac{6}{5} < \bigg(\frac{5}{3}\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} < I(m) < 2$$
which implies that (cont'd. on next comment $\ldots$)

Comment: $$0 < \frac{D(m)}{s(m)} - \frac{D(m^2)}{s(m^2)} = \frac{D(p^k m)}{D(p^k)s(m)} = \frac{2 - I(p^k)I(m)}{(2 - I(p^k))(I(m) - 1)} < \frac{\bigg(2 - \bigg(5/3\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}\bigg)}{\bigg(4/5\bigg)\bigg(\bigg(5/3\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} - 1\bigg)} \approx 1.294379112661269883108650 < \bigg(5/3\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} < I(m),$$
where
$$\bigg(5/3\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} \approx 1.49127898974637235580.$$