# A formula for $D(x)D(y) - D(xy)$ in terms of the sum-of-aliquot-divisors function, when $\gcd(x,y)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, closed-form, arithmetic-functions

Hereinafter, we shall let $\sigma(z)$ be the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $z$.  Denote the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $z$ by $D(z) = 2z - \sigma(z)$, and the [sum of aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $z$ by $s(z) = \sigma(z) - z$.

We shall compute here a formula for $D(x)D(y) - D(xy)$ in terms of the sum-of-aliquot-divisors function, when $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

Suppose that $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

Then we have
$$D(x)D(y) - D(xy) = (2x - \sigma(x))(2y - \sigma(y)) - (2xy - \sigma(xy))$$
$$= 4xy - 2y\sigma(x) - 2x\sigma(y) + \sigma(x)\sigma(y) - 2xy + \sigma(x)\sigma(y),$$
where we have used the condition $\gcd(x,y)=1$ in the last equation to derive $\sigma(xy)=\sigma(x)\sigma(y)$.

This gives
$$D(x)D(y) - D(xy) = 2xy - 2y\sigma(x) - 2x\sigma(y) + 2\sigma(x)\sigma(y)$$
so that we obtain
$$D(x)D(y) - D(xy) = 2y\bigg(x - \sigma(x)\bigg) - 2\sigma(y)\bigg(x - \sigma(x)\bigg)$$
which simplifies to
$$D(x)D(y) - D(xy) = 2\bigg(x - \sigma(x)\bigg)\bigg(y - \sigma(y)\bigg) = 2\bigg(\sigma(x) - x\bigg)\bigg(\sigma(y) - y\bigg) = 2s(x)s(y).$$

Here are my inquiries:

**QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Is it possible to extend the formula
> $$D(x)D(y) - D(xy) = 2s(x)s(y)$$
> to, say, something that uses three or more arguments (which are pairwise coprime)?

> **(2)** If the answer to *Question* **(1)** is *YES*, what is the closed form for the formula and how can it be proved, in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s(x_i):=s_i$.

If $\gcd(x_i,x_j)=1$ for any $(i,j)$ where $1\le i\lt j\le n$, then we have
$$\begin{align}\prod_{i=1}^{n}D(x_i)-D\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\bigg)
&=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2x_i-\sigma(x_i))-2\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\sigma\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i\bigg)
\\\\&=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2x_i-\sigma(x_i))-2\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\prod_{i=1}^{n}\sigma(x_i)
\\\\&=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-s_i)+\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i+s_i)-2\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i
\\\\&=\begin{cases}\displaystyle 2\bigg(\sum_{(n-2,2)}+\sum_{(n-4,4)}+\cdots +\sum_{(0,n)}\bigg)&\text{if $n$ is even}\\\\\displaystyle 2\bigg(\sum_{(n-2,2)}+\sum_{(n-4,4)}+\cdots +\sum_{(1,n-1)}\bigg)&\text{if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

where $\displaystyle\sum_{(i,j)}$ represents the sum of all the terms which are of the form $$\underbrace{xx\cdots xx}_{i}\underbrace{ss\cdots ss}_{j}$$
with $i+j=n$.

---

For example, for $n=4$, we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^{4}D(x_i)-D\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{4}x_i\bigg)$$
$$\small=2\bigg(x_1x_2s_3s_4+x_1x_3s_2s_4+x_1x_4s_2s_3+x_2x_3s_1s_4+x_2x_4s_1s_3+x_3x_4s_1s_2+s_1s_2s_3s_4\bigg)$$

For $n=5$, we have
$$\prod_{i=1}^{5}D(x_i)-D\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{5}x_i\bigg)$$
$$=2\bigg(x_3x_4x_5s_1s_2+x_2x_4x_5s_1s_3+x_2x_3x_5s_1s_4+x_2x_3x_4s_1s_5+x_1x_4x_5s_2s_3+x_1x_3x_5s_2s_4+x_1x_3x_4s_2s_5+x_1x_2x_5s_3s_4+x_1x_2x_4s_3s_5+x_1x_2x_3s_4s_5+x_1s_2s_3s_4s_5+x_2s_1s_3s_4s_5+x_3s_1s_2s_4s_5+x_4s_1s_2s_3s_5+x_5s_1s_2s_3s_4\bigg)$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, @mathlove! Give me some time to review it. An upvote for now! =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own attempt for the case of **three** ($3$) arguments.

Suppose that
$$\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x,z)=\gcd(y,z)=1.$$

Then we have
$$D(x)D(y)D(z) - D(xyz) = (2x-\sigma(x))(2y-\sigma(y))(2z-\sigma(z))-(2xyz-\sigma(xyz))$$
$$=(4xy-2y\sigma(x)-2x\sigma(y)+\sigma(x)\sigma(y))(2z-\sigma(z))-2xyz+\sigma(x)\sigma(y)\sigma(z)$$
$$=8xyz-4yz\sigma(x)-4xz\sigma(y)+2z\sigma(x)\sigma(y)-4xy\sigma(z)+2y\sigma(x)\sigma(z)+2x\sigma(y)\sigma(z)-\sigma(x)\sigma(y)\sigma(z)-2xyz+\sigma(x)\sigma(y)\sigma(z)$$
$$=2xyz-2yz\sigma(x)-2yz\sigma(x)+2z\sigma(x)\sigma(y)$$
$$+2xyz-2xz\sigma(y)-2xz\sigma(y)+2x\sigma(y)\sigma(z)$$
$$+2xyz-2xy\sigma(z)-2xy\sigma(z)+2y\sigma(x)\sigma(z),$$
from which we obtain
$$=2yz(x-\sigma(x))-2z\sigma(x)(y-\sigma(y))$$
$$+2xz(y-\sigma(y))-2x\sigma(y)(z-\sigma(z))$$
$$+2xy(z-\sigma(z))-2y\sigma(z)(x-\sigma(x))$$
from which we get
$$=2y(x-\sigma(x))(z-\sigma(z))+2z(y-\sigma(y))(x-\sigma(x))+2x(z-\sigma(z))(y-\sigma(y)).$$

> This finally gives the formula
> $$D(x)D(y)D(z)-D(xyz)=2\bigg(xs(y)s(z)+ys(x)s(z)+zs(x)s(y)\bigg).$$

> Checking the formula for $(x,y,z)=(3,5,7)$ gives
> $$D(x)D(y)D(z)-D(xyz)=D(3)D(5)D(7)-D(105)=2\cdot{4}\cdot{6}-18=48-18=30$$
> $$2\bigg(xs(y)s(z)+ys(x)s(z)+zs(x)s(y)\bigg)=2\bigg(3\cdot s(5)s(7)+5\cdot s(3)s(7)+7\cdot s(3)s(5)\bigg)=2\bigg(3\cdot{1}\cdot{1}+5\cdot{1}\cdot{1}+7\cdot{1}\cdot{1}\bigg)=2\cdot{15}=30.$$