# On odd perfect numbers $q^k n^2$ and the deficient-perfect divisor $q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This post is an offshoot of the following [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3746548).)

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  Denote the [*deficiency*](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the [*sum of the aliquot divisors*](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$.

If $\sigma(m)=2m$ and $m$ is odd, then $m$ is called an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  It is currently unknown whether there are any odd perfect numbers, although it is widely believed that there is none.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $m$, if one exists, must have the so-called *Eulerian form*
$$m = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Since the divisor sum function $\sigma$ is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) and $m = q^k n^2$ is perfect, we obtain
$$2 q^k n^2 = 2m=\sigma(m)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)$$
so that we get
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)).$$

From the [hyperlinked MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3746548), letting
$$x = q^{\frac{k-1}{2}},$$
$$y = n^2,$$
and noting that
$$\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(q,n)=1$$
then we obtain
$$D\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)D(n^2) - D\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2\bigg) = 2s\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)s(n^2).$$
But we know that
$$\sigma(n^2)={n^2}\cdot\frac{2q^k}{\sigma(q^k)}$$
$$D\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)=2q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} - \sigma\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)=2q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} - \frac{q^{\frac{k+1}{2} - 1}}{q - 1}=\frac{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 2q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} + 1}{q-1}$$
$$D(n^2)=2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)={2n^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{\sigma(q^k)-q^k}{\sigma(q^k)}\bigg)={2n^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{(q - 1)\sigma(q^k)}\bigg)$$
$$D\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2\bigg)=\frac{2 q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2}{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1}$$
(The last equation is a result of [Holdener and Rachfal](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2019.1584515).)
$$s\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)=\sigma\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)-q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}=\sigma\bigg(q^{\frac{k-3}{2}}\bigg)=\frac{q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} - 1}{q - 1}$$
$$s(n^2)=\sigma(n^2)-n^2={n^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{2q^k - \sigma(q^k)}{\sigma(q^k)}\bigg)={n^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 2q^k + 1}{(q-1)\sigma(q^k)}\bigg)$$
Cancelling $2n^2$ from both sides of
$$D\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)D(n^2) - D\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2\bigg) = 2s\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigg)s(n^2)$$
we obtain
$$\bigg(\frac{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 2q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} + 1}{q-1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{(q - 1)\sigma(q^k)}\bigg)-\frac{q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}}{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1}=\bigg(\frac{q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} - 1}{q - 1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 2q^k + 1}{(q-1)\sigma(q^k)}\bigg).$$

Now, assume that the [Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/) that $k=1$ is true.

Then the first factor on the **RHS** of the last equation evaluates to zero, so that we have (on the **LHS**)
$$\frac{1}{q+1}-\frac{1}{q+1}=0.$$

**However, when I performed an exact computation on both **LHS** and **RHS** of the equation (after cancelling $2n^2$ and multiplying both sides by $\sigma(q^k)$), I am getting:**

$$\text{LHS} = \frac{4q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k+3}{2}}-q^{k+1}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{2k+1}+2q^k-2q^{2k} + q^k - 1}{\bigg(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1\bigg)(q-1)^2}$$
$$\text{RHS} = \frac{-q^{k+1}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}} + 2q^k - 1}{(q-1)^2}.$$

Assuming the veracity of the expressions for
$$\text{LHS} = \bigg(\frac{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 2q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} + 1}{q-1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}\bigg)-\frac{q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \sigma(q^k)}{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1}$$
and
$$\text{RHS} = \bigg(\frac{q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} - 1}{q - 1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 2q^k + 1}{q-1}\bigg),$$
upon cancelling $(q-1)^2$ from both sides, we obtain
$$\frac{4q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k+3}{2}}-q^{k+1}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{2k+1}+2q^k-2q^{2k} + q^k - 1}{\bigg(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1\bigg)}$$
$$=-q^{k+1}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}} + 2q^k - 1.$$
Then, with a goal of simplifying the computations, again assuming that the [Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/) that $k=1$ is true, we have
$$k=1 \implies \frac{4q^2 -2q^3 -q^2 -2q + q^3 + 2q -2q^2 + q - 1}{q + 1}=-q^2+1-2q+q^2+2q-1=0 \implies -q^3 + q^2 + q - 1 = q^2 (1 - q) - (1 - q) = 0 = (q^2 - 1)(1 - q) = 0.$$
The last equation implies that
$$q = \pm 1,$$
which contradicts $q \geq 5$, since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Here are my questions:

> **(1)** Are the expressions
> $$\text{LHS} = \bigg(\frac{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} - 2q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} + 1}{q-1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}\bigg)-\frac{q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \sigma(q^k)}{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1}$$
> $$= \frac{4q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k+3}{2}}-q^{k+1}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{2k+1}+2q^k-2q^{2k} + q^k - 1}{\bigg(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1\bigg)(q-1)^2},$$
> and
> $$\text{RHS} = \bigg(\frac{q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} - 1}{q - 1}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 2q^k + 1}{q-1}\bigg)$$
> $$= \frac{-q^{k+1}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}} + 2q^k - 1}{(q-1)^2}$$
> *algebraically correct*?

> **(2)** If the answer to *Question* **(1)** is **YES**, how do we resolve the apparent contradiction?

*Postscript:* I used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to simplify some of the expressions in the interim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [WolframAlpha computational verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify%20%28q%5E%28%28k%2B1%29%2F2%29%20%2B%201%29%28q%5E%28%28k%2B1%29%2F2%29%20-%202q%5E%28%28k-1%29%2F2%29%20%2B%201%29%28q%5Ek%20-%201%29%20-%20%28q%5E%28%28k-1%29%2F2%29%20%28q%20-%201%29%20%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%201%29%29) for the numerator of the $\text{LHS}$ expression under consideration.

The computation simplifies the expression for $\text{LHS}$ to
$$\text{LHS}=\frac{-q^{k+1}+3q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}-q^{\frac{k+1}{2}}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}-q^{\frac{3k+3}{2}}+q^{2k+1}+3q^k-2q^{2k}-1}{\bigg(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1\bigg)(q-1)^2}$$
which *does not agree* with the prior computation above.

Likewise, here is the [WolframAlpha computational verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify%20%28q%5E%28%28k-1%29%2F2%29%20-%201%29%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20-%202q%5Ek%20%2B%201%29) for the numerator of the $\text{RHS}$ expression under consideration.

The computation simplifies the expression for $\text{RHS}$ to
$$\text{RHS}=\frac{-q^{k+1}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}+2q^k-1}{(q-1)^2}$$
which *agrees* with the prior computation above.

Equating $\text{LHS}=\text{RHS}$ and cancelling $(q-1)^2$ from both sides, we obtain
$$\frac{-q^{k+1}+3q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}-q^{\frac{k+1}{2}}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}-q^{\frac{3k+3}{2}}+q^{2k+1}+3q^k-2q^{2k}-1}{q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1}$$
$$=-q^{k+1}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}+2q^k-1.$$

Finally, here is the [WolframAlpha computational verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify%20%28q%5E%28%28k%2B1%29%2F2%29%20%2B%201%29%28-q%5E%28k%2B1%29%20%2B%20q%5E%28%28k-1%29%2F2%29%20-%202q%5E%28%283k-1%29%2F2%29%20%2B%20q%5E%28%283k%2B1%29%2F2%29%20%2B%202q%5Ek%20-%201%29) for the product
$$\bigg(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}} + 1\bigg)\bigg(-q^{k+1}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}+2q^k-1\bigg).$$
The computation comes out to
$$-q^{k+1}+2q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}-q^{\frac{3k+3}{2}}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-q^{\frac{k+1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}+q^k-2q^{2k}+q^{2k+1}+2q^k-1$$
$$=-q^{k+1}+3q^{\frac{3k+1}{2}}-q^{\frac{3k+3}{2}}+q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-q^{\frac{k+1}{2}}-2q^{\frac{3k-1}{2}}+3q^k-2q^{2k}+q^{2k+1}-1,$$
which agrees with the numerator of the $\text{LHS}$.

**Hence, there is actually NO CONTRADICTION, as the equation is in fact an IDENTITY.**