# On odd perfect numbers $q^k n^2$ and the deficient-perfect divisor $q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2$ - Part II

Tags: number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers, open-problem

(This question is an offshoot of this earlier [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3765328).)

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  Denote the [*deficiency*](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the [*sum of the aliquot divisors*](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $x$ by $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

If $\sigma(m)=2m$ and $m$ is odd, then $m$ is called an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  It is currently unknown whether there are any odd perfect numbers, although it is widely believed that there is none.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $m$, if one exists, must have the so-called *Eulerian form*
$$m = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Since the divisor sum function $\sigma$ is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) and $m = q^k n^2$ is perfect, we obtain
$$2 q^k n^2 = 2m=\sigma(m)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)$$
which implies that
$$2 = \dfrac{\sigma(m)}{m} = \dfrac{\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}\bigg)}\Bigg)}{{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}\bigg)}} \leq \dfrac{\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)}{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\cdot\dfrac{\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}{n^2}\Bigg)}{q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}} = I\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg)I(d),$$
where
$$d = q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}.$$

We now compute
$$\dfrac{d}{D(d)} = \dfrac{q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}}{2q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2} - \dfrac{\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} - 1\bigg)\sigma(n^2)}{q - 1}} = \dfrac{q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}}{2q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2} - \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)}{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} + 1}} = \dfrac{q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}}{2q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2} - \dfrac{2q^k n^2}{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} + 1}},$$
which simplifies to
$$\dfrac{d}{D(d)} = \dfrac{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} + 1}{2\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} + 1\Bigg) - 2\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\Bigg)} = \dfrac{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} + 1}{2}.$$
This confirms a theorem of [Holdener and Rachfal](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2019.1584515).  (That is, the proper divisor
$$d = q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}$$
of an odd perfect number
$$m = q^k n^2$$
must be [deficient-perfect](http://oeis.org/A271816).)

So now we have the inequality
$$\dfrac{2}{I\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg)} \leq I(d),$$
which implies that
$$\dfrac{D(d)}{d} = 2 - I(d) \leq 2 - \dfrac{2}{I\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg)},$$
from which it follows that
$$\dfrac{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} + 1}{2} = \dfrac{d}{D(d)} \geq \dfrac{I\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg)}{2\Bigg(I\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg) - 1\Bigg)}.$$
We therefore have to solve the resulting inequality
$$q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} + 1 \geq \dfrac{I\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg)}{I\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg) - 1} = \dfrac{\dfrac{q^{\dfrac{k+3}{2}} - 1}{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} \bigg(q - 1\bigg)}}{\Bigg(\dfrac{q^{\dfrac{k+3}{2}} - 1}{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} \bigg(q - 1\bigg)}\Bigg) - 1}$$
which implies that
$$\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} + 1\Bigg)\cdot\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}} - 1\Bigg) \geq q^{\dfrac{k+3}{2}} - 1$$
from which it follows that
$$q^{k+1} - 1 \geq q^{\dfrac{k+3}{2}} - 1 \implies q^{k+1} \geq q^{\dfrac{k+3}{2}} \implies q^{2k+2} \geq q^{k+3} \implies 2k+2 \geq k+3 \implies k \geq 1.$$

**INQUIRY**

> Is it possible to improve on the approach/attack as outlined in this post to hopefully produce a nontrivial lower bound for $k$?

Comment: You used an inequality $$\sigma\bigg({q^{(k+2)/2}\bigg(q^{(k-1)/2}{n^2}\bigg)}\bigg)\le \sigma\bigg({q^{(k+1)/2}}\bigg)\sigma\bigg({q^{(k-1)/2}}{n^2}\bigg)$$This inequality is true, but I would like to point out that we can have
$$\sigma\bigg({q^{(k+1)/2}\bigg(q^{(k-1)/2}{n^2}\bigg)}\bigg)=\sigma\bigg({q^{(k+1)/2}}\bigg)\sigma\bigg({q^{(k-1)/2}}{n^2}\bigg)-\frac{q(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}-1)(q^{\frac{k+1}{2}}-1)}{(q-1)^2}\sigma(n^2)$$
though I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @mathlove, but I do not follow.  What identity/property are you using to derive the last equation in your comment?

Comment: I've just added an explanation.

Comment: I am accepting @mathlove's answer for now, since it introduces a new attack/approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long to comment* :

You used an inequality
$$\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}\bigg)}\Bigg)\le \sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}{n^2}\Bigg)$$

This inequality is true, but we can have
$$\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}\bigg)}\Bigg)$$
$$=\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}{n^2}\Bigg)-\frac{q\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}-1\Bigg)\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}-1\Bigg)}{(q-1)^2}\sigma(n^2)$$
since we have
$$\begin{align}&\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}{n^2}\Bigg)-\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}\bigg)}\Bigg)
\\\\&=\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma({n^2})-\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)
\\\\&=\Bigg(\frac{q^{\dfrac{k+3}{2}}-1}{q-1}\cdot\frac{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}-1}{q-1}-\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}\Bigg)\sigma(n^2)
\\\\&=\frac{\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+3}{2}}-1\Bigg)\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}-1\Bigg)-(q^{k+1}-1)(q-1)}{(q-1)^2}\sigma(n^2)
\\\\&=\frac{q\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}-1\Bigg)\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}-1\Bigg)}{(q-1)^2}\sigma(n^2)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, @mathlove!  Now I understand.  =)

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : You are welcome. I made some parentheses bigger:)

Comment: Just one minor question, @mathlove:  Does your obtained identity imply that
$$(q - 1)^2 \mid s(q^k),$$
where
$$s(q^k) = \dfrac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}?$$
Or does it imply that
$$(q - 1) \mid \sigma(n^2),$$
since $\gcd(q,q-1)=1$?

Comment: My apologies, I was of course assuming that $k \neq 1$ in my last comment, @mathlove.

Comment: There was a **typo** in my second-to-the-last comment, it should have been as follows, @mathlove:

Just one minor question: Does your obtained identity imply that
$$(q - 1) \mid s(q^k),$$
where
$$s(q^k) = \dfrac{q^k - 1}{q - 1}?$$
Or does it imply that
$$(q - 1) \mid \sigma(n^2),$$
since $\gcd(q,q-1)=1$?

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Where does $s(q^k)$ come from? Do you think that $\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}-1\bigg)\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}-1\bigg)=q^k-1$ holds? This does not hold in general.

Comment: Oops, my bad!  I thought there was an alternating plus and minus there.  =(