# On odd perfect numbers $q^k n^2$ and the deficient-perfect divisor $q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2$ - Part III

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(Preamble: This question is an offshoot of this [answer by mathlove to an earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3869227/28816).)

Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ denote the *classical sum of the divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

If $\sigma(m)=2m$ and $m$ is odd, then $m$ is called an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  It is currently unknown whether there are any odd perfect numbers, although it is widely believed that there is none.

Euler proved that an odd perfect number $m$, if one exists, must have the so-called *Eulerian form*
$$m = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Since the divisor sum function $\sigma$ is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) and $m = q^k n^2$ is perfect, we obtain
$$2 q^k n^2 = 2m=\sigma(m)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2).$$

From the hyperlinked [answer by mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3869227/28816), we have:

> We can have
> $$\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}\bigg)}\Bigg)$$
> $$=\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}{n^2}\Bigg)-\frac{q\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}-1\Bigg)\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}-1\Bigg)}{(q-1)^2}\sigma(n^2)$$
> since we have
> $$\begin{align}&\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}{n^2}\Bigg)-\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}\bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}{n^2}\bigg)}\Bigg)
> \\\\&=\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma({n^2})-\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)
> \\\\&=\Bigg(\frac{q^{\dfrac{k+3}{2}}-1}{q-1}\cdot\frac{q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}-1}{q-1}-\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}\Bigg)\sigma(n^2)
> \\\\&=\frac{\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+3}{2}}-1\Bigg)\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}-1\Bigg)-(q^{k+1}-1)(q-1)}{(q-1)^2}\sigma(n^2)
> \\\\&=\frac{q\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}-1\Bigg)\Bigg(q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}-1\Bigg)}{(q-1)^2}\sigma(n^2)\end{align}$$

Note that the last equation is equivalent to
$$\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma(n^2)-\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)={q\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-3}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)}{\sigma(n^2)} \text{ (*)},$$
and that $\gcd(q,\sigma(q^j))=1$ for all positive integers $j$.

Now, assume that $k \neq 1$.  Since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $k \geq 5$.

But we know that $q \mid \sigma(n^2)$ holds because
$$\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\dfrac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
(which follows from $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$) implies that
$$\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}=q^{k-1} \cdot{\dfrac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}}=q^{k-1} \cdot{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}.$$
We obtain
$${q} \mid \text{LHS of Equation (*)},$$
which means that
$$q^2 \mid \text{RHS of Equation (*)}.$$
We therefore get
$$q^3 \mid \text{LHS of Equation (*)},$$
which implies that
$$q^4 \mid \text{RHS of Equation (*)}.$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\ldots$$
This results in too many $q$'s, dividing $\sigma(n^2)$, on each side of the equation, resulting to a *contradiction*. (**???**)  (Notice that we know that the maximal power of $q$ that can divide $\sigma(n^2)$ is $q^k$.)

**We therefore conclude that $k=1$.**

Here is my inquiry:

> Have I indeed stumbled upon a contradiction?  If my proof is not sound, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?

Comment: Let $T:=\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)-\sigma(q^k)$. Dividing the both sides of $\text{(*)}$ by $\sigma(n^2)$, one has $T={q\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-3}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)}$. Since $q\ ||\ {q\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-3}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)}$, one has $q\ ||\ T$. This implies that $q^{k+1}\ ||\ \text{LHS of (*)}$ and $q^{k+1}\ ||\ \text{RHS of (*)}$. In your argument, I don't get how you got $q^3\ \mid\ \text{LHS of Equation (*)}$ from $q^2\ \mid\ \text{RHS of Equation (*)}$.

Comment: Please write out your last comment as an actual answer, @mathlove, so that I can upvote.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T:=\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k+1}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)-\sigma(q^k)$. Dividing the both sides of $\text{(*)}$ by $\sigma(n^2)$, one has $T={q\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-3}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)}$. Since $q\ ||\ {q\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-3}{2}}}\Bigg)\sigma\Bigg({q^{\dfrac{k-1}{2}}}\Bigg)}$, one has $q\ ||\ T$. This implies that $q^{k+1}\ ||\ \text{LHS of (*)}$ and $q^{k+1}\ ||\ \text{RHS of (*)}$.

In your argument, I don't get how you got $q^3\ \mid\ \text{LHS of (*)}$ from $q^2\ \mid\ \text{RHS of (*)}$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, @mathlove!  Accepting it now.