# An inequality relating the deficiency and sum of aliquot divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

In what follows, we let $n$ be a positive integer.  The classical sum of divisors of $n$ is given by $\sigma_1(n)$.

Denote the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $n$ by $D(n)=2n-\sigma_1(n)$, and denote the [sum of aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of $n$ by $s(n)=\sigma_1(n)-n$.

(Hereinafter, I shall abbreviate the notation for the divisor sum $\sigma_1$ simply as $\sigma$.)

Here is my question:

> Is the following inequality true in general, where $\gcd(a,b)=1$?
> $$D(ab) < D(a)s(b)$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, we can rewrite
$$D(ab) = 2ab - \sigma(ab) = 2ab - \sigma(a)\sigma(b)$$
$$D(a)s(b) = (2a - \sigma(a))(\sigma(b) - b) = -2ab - \sigma(a)\sigma(b) + 2a\sigma(b) + b\sigma(a).$$

Therefore, we get
$$D(ab) - D(a)s(b) = \bigg(2ab - \sigma(a)\sigma(b)\bigg) - \bigg(-2ab - \sigma(a)\sigma(b) + 2a\sigma(b) + b\sigma(a)\bigg),$$
from which we obtain
$$D(ab) - D(a)s(b) = 4ab - 2a\sigma(b) - b\sigma(a) = ab + (2ab - 2a\sigma(b)) + (ab - b\sigma(a)) = ab + 2a(b - \sigma(b)) + b(a - \sigma(a)) = ab - 2as(b) - bs(a).$$
Alas, this is where I get stuck.  I currently do not see an easy way to get an upper bound of $0$ for
$$ab - 2as(b) - bs(a)$$
when $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: I am currently running a Pari-GP script in [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) to check for counterexamples to the inequality.

Comment: There are infinitely many counterexamples. If $a,b$ are distinct odd prime numbers, then $D(ab)-D(a)s(b)=(a-1)(b-2)-2\ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @mathlove!  This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3820664/28816) to a closely related question encapsulates what I intended to ask, and proves in particular that, for odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$, the inequality
$$\dfrac{D(p^k m)}{D(p^k)s(m)} < 2$$
holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't.

There are infinitely many counterexamples.

If $a,b$ are distinct odd prime numbers, then we have $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and
$$\begin{align}D(ab)-D(a)s(b)&=(2ab-(a+1)(b+1))-(2a-a-1)(b+1-b)
\\\\&=ab-2a-b
\\\\&=(a-1)(b-2)-2
\\\\&\gt 0\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check for counterexamples to the inequality
$$D(xy) < D(x)s(y)$$
where $\gcd(x,y)=1$, using the following **Pari-GP** script in [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/):

```
for(x=1, 1000, for(y=1, 1000, if(2*x*y-sigma(x*y) >= (2*x-sigma(x))*(sigma(y)-y) && gcd(x,y)==1,print(x,"   ",y))))
```

There were several lines returned.  This shows that the inequality is *not true* in general.

Comment: Don't worry this has happened to me many times before. Computer algebra systems update function definitions without informing the user of every single change made, just ensure that for every investigation you conduct, you algebraically define every function used yourself.