# Can this inequality involving the deficiency and sum of aliquot divisors be improved? - Part II

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

This [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3649470/28816) (from April 2020) asked whether the inequality
$$\frac{D(n^2)}{s(n^2)} < \frac{D(n)}{s(n)}$$
could be improved, where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the *deficiency* of the positive integer $x$, $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the *aliquot sum* of $x$, and $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.

In the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3651512/28816), MSE user [Adam Ledger](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/504652) asserts that:

> I am yet to find a counterexample for the following, I have not spent much time on your problem so will appreciate if this is not considered an improvement on your original inequality, but none the less I hope that it helps in some small way:

> Denoting the Kronecker delta as follows:
> $$\delta \left( x,y \right) =\cases{1&$x=y$\cr 0&$x\neq y $\cr}\tag{                             0}$$

> up to $n \leq 2 \cdot 10^7$ I have found the following to be satisfied:
> $${\frac {D \left( n \right) }{s \left( n \right) }}-{\frac {
> D \left( {n}^{2} \right) }{s \left( {n}^{2} \right) }}-\frac{1}{4}
> \delta \left( n-2\,\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor,1 \right) \lt \frac{3}{4} \tag{1}$$

Adam's result implies that we have the bounds
$$0 < \frac{D(n)}{s(n)} - \frac{D(n^2)}{s(n^2)} < 1.$$

Here is my inquiry:

> **QUESTION:** Does anybody here know how to prove Adam's Inequality $(1)$?

**MOTIVATION FOR THE INQUIRY**

Let $N = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3747350/28816) shows that we have
$$\frac{D(m^2)}{s(m^2)}=\frac{D(m)}{s(m)}-\frac{D(p^k m)}{D(p^k)s(m)},$$
which means that, conjecturally, we should have
$$\frac{D(p^k m)}{D(p^k)s(m)}=\frac{D(m)}{s(m)}-\frac{D(m^2)}{s(m^2)} < 1$$
by Adam's result.

Denote the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Note that we have the numerical bounds
$$1 < I(p^k) < \frac{5}{4} < \bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} < I(m) < 2,$$
from which we get
$$0 < \frac{D(p^k m)}{D(p^k)s(m)}=\frac{2 - I(p^k)I(m)}{(2 - I(p^k))(I(m) - 1)} < \dfrac{2-\bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}}{\dfrac{3}{4}\bigg(\bigg(\dfrac{8}{5}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} - 1\bigg)} \approx 1.666929067.$$

**Alas, this is where I get stuck!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer proves that for every $n\gt 1$, $$\dfrac{D(n)}{s(n)} - \dfrac{D(n^2)}{s(n^2)} < 1\tag2$$ holds.

To prove $(2)$, it is sufficient to prove the following claims.

Let $f(n):=(\sigma(n)-2n)\sigma(n^2)+n^3$.

**Claim 1** : $(2)$ is equivalent to $f(n)\gt 0$.

**Claim 2** : If $p$ is a prime number and $k$ is a positive integer, then $f(p^k)\gt 0$.

**Claim 3** : If $f(n)\gt 0$ and $p$ is a prime number satisfying $\gcd(p,n)=1$ and $k$ is a positive integer, then $f(p^kn)\gt 0$.

---

**Example** : $f(2^4)\gt 0$ (claim 2) $\implies f(2^43^2)\gt 0$ (claim 3) $\implies f(2^43^25^3)\gt 0$ (claim 3).

---

**Claim 1** : $(2)$ is equivalent to $f(n)\gt 0$.

*Proof* :

$$\frac{D(n)}{s(n)}-\frac{D(n^2)}{s(n^2)}=\bigg(\frac{n}{\sigma(n)-n}-1\bigg)-\bigg(\frac{n^2}{\sigma(n^2)-n^2}-1\bigg)$$
$$=\frac{n}{\sigma(n)-n}-\frac{n^2}{\sigma(n^2)-n^2}=\frac{n\sigma(n^2)-n^2\sigma(n)}{(\sigma(n)-n)(\sigma(n^2)-n^2)}$$

So, we have
$$\begin{align}&\frac{D(n)}{s(n)}-\frac{D(n^2)}{s(n^2)}\lt 1\iff \frac{n\sigma(n^2)-n^2\sigma(n)}{(\sigma(n)-n)(\sigma(n^2)-n^2)}\lt 1
\\\\&\iff n\sigma(n^2)-n^2\sigma(n)\lt (\sigma(n)-n)(\sigma(n^2)-n^2)
\\\\&\iff n\sigma(n^2)-n^2\sigma(n)\lt \sigma(n)\sigma(n^2)-n^2\sigma(n)-n\sigma(n^2)+n^3
\\\\&\iff (\sigma(n)-2n)\sigma(n^2)+n^3\gt 0\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

---

**Claim 2** : If $p$ is a prime number and $k$ is a positive integer, then $f(p^k)\gt 0$.

*Proof* :

$$\begin{align}f(p^k)&=(\sigma(p^k)-2p^k)\sigma(p^{2k})+p^{3k}
\\\\&=\bigg(\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}-2p^k\bigg)\frac{p^{2k+1}-1}{p-1}+p^{3k}
\\\\&=\frac{p^k-1}{(p-1)^2}\bigg(\underbrace{p^k(p^{k}-p  +1) - 1}_{\text{positive}}\bigg)
\\\\&\gt 0\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

---

**Claim 3** : If $f(n)\gt 0$ and $p$ is a prime number satisfying $\gcd(p,n)=1$ and $k$ is a positive integer, then $f(p^kn)\gt 0$.

*Proof* :

$$\begin{align}f(p^kn)&=(\sigma(p^kn)-2p^kn)\sigma(p^{2k}n^2)+p^{3k}n^3
\\\\&=(\sigma(p^k)\sigma(n)-2p^kn)\sigma(p^{2k})\sigma(n^2)+p^{3k}n^3
\\\\&=\bigg(\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}\sigma(n)-2p^kn\bigg)\frac{p^{2k+1}-1}{p-1}\sigma(n^2)+p^{3k}n^3\end{align}$$

So, we have
$$\small\begin{align}&(p-1)^2f(p^kn)
\\\\&=\bigg((p^{k+1}-1)\sigma(n)-2p^kn(p-1)\bigg)(p^{2k+1}-1)\sigma(n^2)+p^{3k}n^3(p-1)^2
\\\\&=\bigg((p^{k+1}-1)\sigma(n)-p^k(p-1)\sigma(n)+p^k(p-1)\sigma(n)-2p^k(p-1)n\bigg)(p^{2k+1}-1)\sigma(n^2)
\\&\qquad +p^{3k}n^3(p-1)^2
\\\\&=\bigg((p^{k+1}-1)\sigma(n)-p^k(p-1)\sigma(n)\bigg)(p^{2k+1}-1)\sigma(n^2)
\\&\qquad +\bigg(p^k(p-1)\sigma(n)-2p^k(p-1)n\bigg)(p^{2k+1}-1)\sigma(n^2)+p^{3k}n^3(p-1)^2
\\\\&=(p^k-1)(p^{2k+1}-1)\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2)
\\&\qquad +p^k(p-1)\underbrace{(\sigma(n)-2n)\sigma(n^2)}_{\gt -n^3}(p^{2k+1}-1)+p^{3k}n^3(p-1)^2
\\\\&\gt(p^k-1)(p^{2k+1}-1)\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2)
\\&\qquad +p^k(p-1)(-n^3)(p^{2k+1}-1)+p^{3k}n^3(p-1)^2
\\\\&=(p^k-1)(p^{2k+1}-1)\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2) -n^3 (p - 1) p^k (p^{2 k} - 1)
\\\\&=(p^k-1)(p^{2k+1}-1)\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2)-(p - 1) p^k (p^{2 k} - 1)\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2)
\\&\qquad +(p - 1) p^k (p^{2 k} - 1)\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2) - (p - 1) p^k (p^{2 k} - 1)n^3
\\\\&=\bigg((p^k-1)(p^{2k+1}-1)-(p - 1) p^k (p^{2 k} - 1)\bigg)\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2)
\\&\qquad +(p - 1) p^k (p^{2 k} - 1)(\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2) - n^3)
\\\\&=(p^k - 1)\bigg( \underbrace{p^k(p^{k}-p +1) - 1}_{\text{positive}}\bigg)\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2)
\\&\qquad +(p - 1) p^k (p^{2 k} - 1)\bigg(\underbrace{\sigma(n)\sigma(n^2) - n^3}_{\text{positive}}\bigg)
\\\\&\gt 0\end{align}$$
Hence, $f(p^kn)\gt 0$ follows.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: Allow me to review your answer in the next couple of days, @mathlove!  An upvote for now.  =)

Comment: Great answer. I was wondering about a justification of the $(σ(n)−2n)σ(n^2)>-n^3$ inequality and I think one is that it holds for all primes and is equivalent to $(I(n)-2)I(n^2)>-1$. Therefore the latter inequality holds for all primes, and as if $p$ divides $n$ then $I(p)\leq I(n)$, $(I(n)-2)I(n^2)\geq (I(p)-2)I(p^2)>-1$.

Comment: I agree that it is a great answer.  I am hereby accepting your answer, @mathlove!  =)