# A proposed unconditional factor-chain proof for the inequality $I(n) > \frac{3}{2}$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: solution-verification, factoring, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be a **hypothetical odd perfect number** given in *Eulerian form*.  (That is, $q$ is the *special/Euler prime* satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.)

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, and the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

This post attempts to prove that the inequality $I(n) > 3/2$ holds unconditionally, using a variation on the factor chain method.

---

Assume to the contrary that $I(n) \leq 3/2$.  As shown in this [answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2977546/28816), $I(n) \neq 3/2$.  Furthermore, it is also shown there that $I(n) < 3/2$ implies $q = 5$.

We get the series of implications:
$$I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \implies q = 5 \implies 3 = \frac{q + 1}{2} \mid \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \mid n^2 \implies 3 \mid n \text{ (since } 3 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies \frac{4}{3} = I(3) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$3 \mid n^2 \implies 3^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(3^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2$$
$$\implies 13 \mid n^2 \implies 13 \mid n \text{ (since } 13 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies \frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{14}{13} = I(3)I(13) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$13 \mid n^2 \implies 13^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(13^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2 \implies 183 = 3\cdot{61} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 61 \mid n^2 \implies 61 \mid n \text{ (since } 61 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies \frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{14}{13}\cdot\frac{62}{61} = I(3)I(13)I(61) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$61 \mid n^2 \implies 61^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(61^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2 \implies 3783 = 3\cdot{13}\cdot{97} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 97 \mid n^2 \implies 97 \mid n \text{ (since } 97 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies \frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{14}{13}\cdot\frac{62}{61}\cdot\frac{98}{97} = I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$97 \mid n^2 \implies 97^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(97^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2 \implies 9507 = 3\cdot{3169} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 3169 \mid n^2 \implies 3169 \mid n \text{ (since } 3169 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$3169 \mid n^2 \implies 3169^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(3169^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2$$
$$\implies 10045731 = 3\cdot{3348577} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 3348577 \mid n^2 \implies 3348577 \mid n \text{ (since } 3348577 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$3348577 \mid n^2 \implies 3348577^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(3348577^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2$$
$$\implies 11212971273507 = 3\cdot{3737657091169} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 3737657091169 \mid n^2 \implies 3737657091169 \mid n \text{ (since } 3737657091169 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577)I(3737657091169) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$3737657091169 \mid n^2 \implies 3737657091169^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(3737657091169^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2$$
$$\implies 13970080531169648034877731 = 3\cdot{181}\cdot{26042690887}\cdot{987900542491} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 181 \mid n^2 \implies 181 \mid n \text{ (since } 181 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies 26042690887 \mid n^2 \implies 26042690887 \mid n \text{ (since } 26042690887 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies 987900542491 \mid n^2 \implies 987900542491 \mid n \text{ (since } 987900542491 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577)I(3737657091169)I(181)I(26042690887)I(987900542491) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2} \text{ (no contradiction) }$$
$$181 \mid n^2 \implies 181^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(181^2) \mid \sigma(n^2) \mid N = 5^k n^2 \implies 32943 = 3\cdot{79}\cdot{139} \mid n^2$$
$$\implies 79 \mid n^2 \implies 79 \mid n \text{ (since } 79 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
$$\implies 139 \mid n^2 \implies 139 \mid n \text{ (since } 139 \text{ is squarefree) }$$
But this implies that
$$I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577)I(3737657091169)I(181)I(26042690887)I(987900542491)I(79)I(139) \leq I(n) < \frac{3}{2},$$
where we have the approximation
$$I(3)I(13)I(61)I(97)I(3169)I(3348577)I(3737657091169)I(181)I(26042690887)I(987900542491)I(79)I(139) \approx 1.512675290866383731626612,$$
which is a **contradiction**.

---

We therefore conclude that the inequality
$$I(n) > \frac{3}{2}$$
must hold unconditionally.

---

Here are my inquiries:

> **QUESTIONS:** Is this argument sound?  If not, can it be mended so as to produce a valid proof?

Comment: It is not true that $3^2 \mid n^2 \implies \sigma(3^2) \mid \sigma(n^2)$. Take $n=9$.

Comment: I get your point, @mathlove. So, I think that in order to mend the proof, I should do
$$3^2 \parallel n^2 \implies \sigma(3^2) \mid \sigma(n^2)$$ and proceed similarly with the rest of the other primes.

Comment: FYI, if you replace $3^2\mid n^2$ with $3^2\ ||\ n^2$ in "$3\mid n^2\implies 3^2\mid n^2\implies \sigma(3^2)\mid \sigma(n^2)$", then although it is true that $3^2\ ||\ n^2\implies \sigma(3^2)\mid \sigma(n^2)$, it is not true that $3 \mid n^2\implies 3^2\ ||\ n^2$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that caveat, @mathlove. It will be an additional assumption.